# D3 word cloud : Which is better cloud layout or force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was learning D3 and came to know about force layout and cloud layout. What is the difference between these two.
As force layout is giving all the functionalities for creating word cloud, then why cloud layout is required.
I want to create word cloud, which is better?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I also like to know what are the advantages and disadvantage for using  d3 force layout for creating word cloud  instead of Word cloud layout by Jason Davies, https://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/

Comment: Did you have a look at any of the examples? That should make it pretty clear what the differences are.